# How to pass an attribute from an object to another to calculate a value

Tags: python, object, attributes

**Goal: calculate a value based on the sum of attributes of another object, and an attribute from the current object an then use that value to subtract from another value**

Expected Output: target_value = 5

Issue: AttributeError: type object 'x' has no attribute 'attribute1'

Object 1:

```
class x():

  def __init__(self, attribute1):
    self.attribute1 = attribute1
```

Object 2:

```
from object_one import x

class y():

  def __init__(self, attribute2):
    self.attribute2 = attribute2
  
  def calculate_attributes(self, target):
    value = x.attribute1 + y.attribute2
    target -= value
```

Main:

```
from object_one import x
from object_two import y

object_x = x(5)
object_y = y(10)

target_value = 20

object_y.calculate_attributes(target_value)
print(target_value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A direct solution to your problem

In Object 1, you are declaring the *field* attribute1. In Object2, you are importing the *class* X.

The *class* X does not have an attribute of name `attribute1` - only an object of type `x` does. You would have to pass in a reference to the original object `x` into the `calculate_attributes(self, target)` method by adding a parameter, like below:

```
class y():

  def __init__(self, attribute2):
    self.attribute2 = attribute2
  
  def calculate_attributes(self, target, x_obj):
    value = x_obj.attribute1 + y.attribute2
    target -= value
```

After that, you would use this calculate_attributes method by doing:

```
object_y.calculate_attributes(target_value, object_x)
```

### A more in depth explanation - why did this happen?

A class is, basically, a blueprint for an *object*. After defining a class, you can use it by *instantiating* an object of its type.

With the line

```
object_x = x(5)
```

You are making an object of the *type* x.

This object has its own fields - it is alive on its own, and is simply created from the blueprint that is its class (herein: "type", "blueprint", "parent class" - all mean the same thing when I speak here).

In the `__init__` method, when you set `self.attribute2` to the parameter with the same name, you set a *field* of that any *object* of that class that is instantiated. This means that two `y` type objects can have a different value of `attribute2`

However, you can *also* make the class contain a "field". This can be done like below:

```
class y():
  who_made_this_class = "george"
  def __init__(self, attribute2):
    self.attribute2 = attribute2
```

This can be referred to as a static class variable. Now, when you instantiate a new `y` object, you see the behaviour shown below:

```
obj_one = y(15);
obj_two = y(2020);

print("Object ones attribute2 value is: " + str(obj_one.attribute2))
print("Object twos attribute2 value is: " + str(obj_two.attribute2))

print("Object ones who_made_this_class value is: " + str(obj_one.who_made_this_class))
print("Object twos who_made_this_class value is: " + str(obj_two.who_made_this_class))
```

Expected output is:

```
Object ones attribute2 value is: 15
Object twos attribute2 value is: 2020

Object ones who_made_this_class value is: george
Object twos who_made_this_class value is: george
```

Comment: Do not name variables CamelCase as it violates PEP8 Code style conventions. Rename xObj to x_obj.

Comment: I object to PEP ;) Edited in accordance though.

Comment: You forgot to also rename xObj in method parameters)

Comment: Sry making a bigger edit to explain OOP class fields - will fix that then.